# Why is my HTTP message marked as being chunked?

Tags: java, http, netty, chunking

I am using Netty 3.10.5 and HttpClientCodec. A certain received HTTP response always is being marked as chunked, though it really is not. This is quite bad, because the response never gets through the following HttpChunkAggregator, because no HTTP chunks are produced by HttpClientCodec.

The received response contains some content, which is less than the maximum chunk size. But the response has no content length header. With debugging I found that  HttpMessageDecoder, which is a ReplayingDecoder, goes here to check for chunking:

```
case READ_VARIABLE_LENGTH_CONTENT:
if (buffer.readableBytes() > maxChunkSize || HttpHeaders.is100ContinueExpected(message)) {
    // Generate HttpMessage first.  HttpChunks will follow.
    checkpoint(State.READ_VARIABLE_LENGTH_CONTENT_AS_CHUNKS);
    message.setChunked(true);
    return message;
}
break;
```

With ReplayingDecoder, the used method `readableBytes()` in my case returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE - buf().readerIndex();`

This is why my message is marked as chunked. But isn't this check maybe some kind of buggy?

Comment: chunking should be transparent to app. Any http API that forces users to know about chunking is ill designed. Nevertheless, it should not be a problem  if the http library presents a non-chunked message as a chunked message to app.

Comment: I think the problem maybe there is no content-length header, right? Because your content is less than the maximum chunk size.

Comment: Yes, the message itself is not perfect. But if the Netty check for reabable bytes would return the correct number, then I think the processing of this imperfect message would be no problem.